# setDate method returns a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying this code in my browser's console:

```js
var today = new Date()
var priorDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-30)
```

The issue that I am facing is that priorDate is a string, not a date object.

[image]

Any idea on what I might be doing wrong here? I want the prior date to be a date object as well.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`setDate method returns a string`***

No it's not. It returns `number`.

[`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) **Return value**

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date (the Date object is also changed in place).

I believe you want the changed object not the return value.

Try the following:

```js
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate()-30);
console.log(today);
```

Comment: Thanks. So, I was setting the priorDate as the return value of the setDate method.